# Sort todo.txt items by due date in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, regex, io, to-do-list

I am using the following format for my task management: https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt

```
Do some stuff +uni due:2022-12-31
Write some paper +uni due:2023-01-10
```

I am not using the syntax for priority.

I know there is a command-line tool one can install to manage items but I just needed a sort function and decided to write it myself. I am not very experienced in Python so I would like to have your insights

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
from datetime import datetime, time
import argparse

DATE_PATTERN = re.compile(r"due:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")

def get_due_date(item):
    match = DATE_PATTERN.search(item)
    if not match:
        return time.max
    date_str = match.group(1)
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

def sort_todos(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r") as fh:
        lines = fh.readlines()
    lines.sort(key=get_due_date)
    with open(filepath, "w") as fh:
        fh.write("".join(lines))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filepath", help="Path to the file with todo items")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sort_todos(args.filepath)
```

Comment: Presumably you are running this against a sample file. Could you post that file?

Comment: @Reinderien I added a dummy example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a short script/utility, but it's very clear and well written. There's honestly not much to give feedback on.

Some (very) minor improvements:

- use `pathlib.Path` and define this as the `type` for the `filepath` arg; that way you can just use `Path.read_text()` and `Path.write_text` and not have to use the context handlers
- sort your imports alphabetically, use type hints, and increase the spacing (PEP8 recommends 2 empty lines between global functions)
- turn `get_due_date()` into an internal/local function - it's only used by `sort_todos()` anyway
- store the date format in a variable (you could even have this as an argument to be more flexible with your todo-files)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from pathlib import Path
import re

DATE_PATTERN = re.compile(r"due:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")
DATE_FMT = "%Y-%m-%d"


def sort_todos(filepath: Path) -> None:
    def get_due_date(item: str) -> date:
        match = DATE_PATTERN.search(item)
        if not match:
            return time.max
        date_str = match.group(1)
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, DATE_FMT).date()

    lines = filepath.read_text().split("\n")
    lines.sort(key=get_due_date)
    filepath.write_text("\n".join(lines))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Utility to sort todo-items in files")
    parser.add_argument("filepath", type=Path, help="File to sort")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sort_todos(args.filepath)
```

I wouldn't personally bother with docstrings for something this short and straight-forward, but they would be good to have if you're building something bigger---especially if it's a library to be used by others. But at that stage there would be other considerations too; packaging, tests, deployment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you picked a sensible approach and you structured your code in an intuitive way. Your formatting is good and the code is readable.

I do want to point out a couple things, though.

First, a naming nitpick - I'm not a huge fan of the variable name `fh`. Sure, it's clear from context what it contains and how it's used, but I still think a more descriptive name (even just `file`) would be an improvement. I'm also not a big fan of how the same variable name gets re-used for two distinct values so close to eachothers in the same function.

It's also not *entirely* clear from the name that `sort_todos` operates on a file rather than, say, a list. The current name is fine, but I might be tempted to rename it to something like `sort_todo_file` instead.

I also think that function could usefully take a separate input and output file. Being able to specify those independently might enable some useful-seeming patterns like `cat todo_1.txt todo_2.txt | sort_todo.py - todo_all.txt`. Consider:

```py
def sort_todos(input_path, output_path):
    with open(input_path, "r") as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()
    lines.sort(key=get_due_date)
    with open(output_path, "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write("".join(lines))
```

If not planning to do that, I do question why that function opens the file twice. It seems it'd be easier to open it just once like so:

```py
def sort_todos(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "rw") as todo_file:
        lines = todo_file.readlines()
        lines.sort(key=get_due_date)
        todo_file.write("".join(lines))
```

I'd also suggest adding docstrings to your functions, making it easier for readers to get an overview of what the functions do without having to read their implementations - sure the implementations are short and readable, but it's still good practice in general.

Similarly, type hints tend to make it easier to understand the design and data-flow of complicated programs. Now, this program isn't very complicated, so it doesn't benefit much from the addition of type hints. But I feel it could still be worth adding them, even if just to get in the habit of using them.

And last and probably also least, a `--help` option is always nice to have, and it's easy enough to add using `ArgumentParser`'s `add_help` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it makes a lot of sense (the only thing is that add_help is already set to True by default). And I get the ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode error if I do a single open

Comment: `--help` (as well as `-h`) is already available with OPs code; the only thing that might be worth adding to supplement it is a description for the argument parser